# INDIRECT function - problem when switching from Excel to Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I built an Excel file then, I converted to Google Sheet.

The file contains 2 tabs:

- The "Consolidated DB" tab contains the raw data (it will be populated by Make with automatic row additions).
- The tab "Parameters Selection" is a dynamic copy of the tab "Consolidated DB" thanks to the following formula:
  =INDIRECT("'Consolidated DB'!L"&LINE()&"C"&COLUMN();FALSE)
  that I wrote in cell A2 of the tab "Parameters Selection" and that I pulled on all my rows and columns.

On Excel the formula works perfectly and returns me as desired the values of each cell of the tab "Consolidated DB" in the tab "Parameters Selection".
However, once I convert the file into a Google sheet it adapts my formula as follows:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(INDIRECT("'Consolidated DB'!L"&LINE()&"C"&COLUMN(),FALSE)), 1, 1)
```

and returns me the error below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vqfry.png)

Do you have any ideas for solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> =INDIRECT("'Consolidated DB'!L"&LINE()&"C"&COLUMN();FALSE)

In Google Sheets, you can copy a larger range with one [{ array expression }](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276), without copying the formula around. Choose **Insert > Sheet** and put this formula in cell `A1` of the new sheet:

```
={ 'Consolidated DB'!A1:Z }
```

The range reference in the above formula will adjust dynamically as you insert and delete rows and columns in the source tab. To keep referencing the same range, regardless of tab layout changes, use this instead:

```
=indirect("Consolidated DB!A1:Z")
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried but it does not work when adding a line above the first one in the tab 'Consolidated DB'. My goal is to recover in the Parameters tab the value of the cells no matter if you add or delete a row.

Comment: I am going to use your formula and start it in A1 as you recommanded thanks you.

Comment: @Raphael56 a formula referencing data can't recover data if deleted. You need to write away/store it's values or it's calculations using VBA if you need something like that

Comment: Edited the answer per OP's new requirements.